# IOS Certificate "Not in keychain" CANNOT delete from xCode | "has 3 iOS Distribution certificates but their private keys are not installed."

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, keychain

I developed an App for IOS a couple years ago. Originally I distributed it to the AppStore from xCode with no issues 4 years ago. Last monday I had to change the developer account linked to the App and the Certificates were all expired. Apple also removed my App from the Appstore due to a conflict with the payment, which is already solved and payed again.

I just followed the guides from Apple with all the info to upload the new version of the App again.
In xCode I added the new developer user which is the administrator and only member of the developer team. I let the program manage the certificates automatically. This was enough to be able to archive and build the new version of the App, but when I try to upload it or validate it is where we get the error.

In the Window --> Organizer, I select the newest build version and click on Distribute App.

Then I select the method IOS App Store --> Upload --> Mark the 3 checkboxes --> Automatically manage signing.

Then I get the error saying: ["Team Name"] has 3 iOS Distribution certificates but their private keys are not installed. Contact the creator of one of these certificates to get a copy of the private key.
I myself am the creator of the certificates and this 3 are installed already in the keychain following the Apple guidelines. But this error keeps popping.

Then I just go to Manage Certificates and i can see not 3 but 6 iOS Distribution Certificates, 3 of those are not in the keychain and im unable to delete them from this menu.

I am running out of ideas on how to solve this since in my developer dashboard at developer.apple.com I can see my 3 certificates and install the keys in the keychain, but for some reason xCode keeps showing 6 certificates.